# Relocation to UK with British child

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, relocation

I am married to a UK citizen who is living in the UK with his child, my stepson, who is also a UK citizen. My husband can't earn the £18,600, due to his situation, caring for a child alone.

I'm a non-EU citizen, living in Lagos with my daughter who is also a UK citizen. How can my daughter and I join my husband stepson? I am the only one who needs a visa.

1) If I accompany my child as a visitor to the UK, do I need to supply my bank statement?

2) Can I relocate to an EU country close to UK with my child, as she can claim to be an EU citizen? My husband and stepson could visit more easily than coming to Lagos every time.

Comment: Would your husband be able to get a 18,600 pound job quickly without the child care issue?

Comment: Sure he can, he had seen many job offer above 19k but couldn’t cope with child care issue over there

Comment: Due to his situation, does he needs to earn 18,600 before we can join him. Thanks for your time and information

Comment: How old is your UK citizen daughter? The EU has ruled recently that parents of EU citizens have rights to residency in some cases. For more see http://www.thejournal.ie/non-eu-residency-3382057-May2017/ and http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-39868868 and https://discoversociety.org/2017/06/06/on-the-frontline-residency-rights-and-non-eu-parents-of-british-citizens/ for some more details.

Comment: She’s 7months old @NatalieN thanks for get involved

Answer (score 1):

1) Probably, yes, but unless you have a compelling reason to returnto Nigeria, your application will likely be met with a refusal.

2) No.  Unfortunately, you cannot derive European Union freedom of movement from your daughter unless *you* are dependant on *her,* which seems unlikely given the circumstances outlined in your question.  You can derive them from your husband, of course, so you could all move to Ireland or some other EU country, but getting you to the UK will be difficult.

Comment: If we all relocate to EU country, how long do you think we’ll live in that country before we’re able to relocate to UK. Thanks for the info

Comment: @Ope1 generally at least six months, but with Brexit looming, the chance of that working out seems to be getting smaller every day.

Comment: Okay, I do understand what you mean. Thanks really appreciate @phoog

Comment: Have a look at this ruling: https://curia.europa.eu/jcms/upload/docs/application/pdf/2017-05/cp170048en.pdf you may have some recourse to 2) should your daughter be underage, and her other parent is not involved in her upbringing.

Comment: I do care for our daughter on day to day basis, he really want us to be with both him and my stepson in uk but I think living in eu country might be best option for myself and daughter

Comment: @Ope1 I think due to the recent case you should have the possibility of coming to the EU based on you being the prime caretaker of your EU citizen daughter. I would get in touch with a lawyer in the prospective country you wish to reside in-- as obtaining the right entry visa and arrival conditions will be very important should you want to stay long term.

Comment: Thanks @Natali N I’ll search for a local lawyer in the country for more information

Comment: Downvoter please explain.